Showing just black silhouette of a model without adding new material
Similar to other creative approaches it good to get a look of your model/ design just by seeing the silhouette.
I want it directly in the viewport as quick, easy way to see, without adding a new material and changing the pass index or any form of shading.

In the viewport shading settings turn on shadow to 100% and changing the shadow shift to 57° (all the way to the right) to get a pitch black model in the viewport.
Together with turning off the viewport overlays, you can brainstorm/ model something without shading or distractions.
If you add both options to your Quick Favourites, you have a easy check occasionally.
(I put both in the quick access while in edit mode, I have less favourites there, so its easier to choose them there)
Also works with ( beveled) curves and any other object.
Be aware, that if you work longer in black, might be overlapping geometry or other issues, that looks good as a silhouette, but not in 3D.
A good way to limit this, is to work from orthographic view, turn on face orientation or just use a extra window just for that purpose.


The trick with viewport shadow works great for low-poly and mid-poly meshes, but it causes immense lags with the dense (sculpted) meshes. Hence, to avoid lags, instead of viewport shadow I recommend to use Flat lighting  (more details in my answer)

For viewing silhouettes I recommend to use Flat lighting.
This option is superior to viewport shadow, because viewport shadow could cause lags in case of dense meshes, while Flat lighting doesn't have this flaw. And less important but also nice thing - Flat lighting gives you an ability to adjust the color of silhouettes.

Detailed instructions:

in the upper right corner you can change lighting to Flat

then Color > Single (and set any color of your choice, e.g. black)




plus it could be useful to disable overlays :


before/after:


*to revert settings back - choose Studio and Material:

and turn overlays back :


That's it :-)
